# libcurl crashes at fwrite() when I set READDATA and READFUNCTION to upload a file

Tags: c++, c, linux, curl, libcurl

I want to use libcurl to chunked upload a file to remote Http server. I call below functions to set READDATA and READFUNCTION to register callback parameters. But libcurl still crashes during curl_easy_perform(). Could anyone help on it? Thanks

What I called:

```
ReadCallbackStatic(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_data.m_lib_curl_handle_ptr, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, ReadCallbackStatic);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_data.m_lib_curl_handle_ptr, CURLOPT_READDATA, userdata);
```

Stack trace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007ffff604741a in fwrite () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00007fffec8713f3 in Curl_client_write () from libcurl.so
#2 0x00007fffec8851b7 in Curl_readwrite () from libcurl.so
#3 0x00007fffec885ea7 in ?? () from libcurl.so
#4 0x00007fffec886a28 in Curl_perform () from libcurl.so
#5 0x00007fffec8873c6 in curl_easy_perform () from libcurl.so
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an actual stack trace.

Comment: [Jay already responded](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/886#issuecomment-227044315) properly to the issue filed in the curl bug, although we miss seeing the code in both places. This is most likely a user error.

Comment: @paddy I added the stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: Without actual code to show the preconditions, this question is pointless.  As @DanielStenberg points out, it could easily be user error.  If you won't make a MCVE to demonstrate the issue, then this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to set CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION too. The crash happens at fwrite() which is used by libcurl by default to handle the http POST response data. After I set CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, the crash disappears. Why the response data is not sent to stdout but fwrite()?

Comment: I work on a big project and it is difficult to show the whole code at here. I have to set both CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, otherwise process crashes with below stack trace. Although libcurl calls fwrite() by default if write data and function are not set. I guess some code in my project unset the default value of CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEDATA. Do you know any function() in libcurl can unset default value for above two options? Thanks.